# XCode: UINavigationItem refuses to show

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

In a UITableView, I'm trying to add a navigation bar (with title and back button, to be precise). I've already embedded this view in a Navigation Controller, and in all of my other views this just worked out of the box but I can't seem to get the bar to show. I have checked the `Shows Navigation Bar' tick in the navigation controller attributes section in the IB.

What am I doing wrong here? What can I do to get my UINavigationItem to show up?

EDIT: Because some answers in other questions suggested doing this: I've already given it a title which I can also retrieve through NSLog.

Answer (score 0):

Is your parent view controller in a navigation controller ? I would suggest put your parent viewcontroller in navigation controller, do what ever action you to do show UItableViewController and push it on navigationcontroller stack. You will have your UItableView in naviagtioncontroller and there will be back button to parent controller.